# Getting garbage after reversing string in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, io, output

I am trying to reverse a string. scanf is working well but when I use fixed string then it gives garbage value. So where is the fault ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char s[50]="Hi I Love Programming";
    char rev[strlen(s)];
    int i,k;



    k=strlen(s);
    for(i=0; i<strlen(s); i++)
    {
        rev[k]=s[i];
    k--;
    }

    printf("The reverse string is: %s\n", rev);
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you get garbage, it means you make a mistake. I suggest you start using a debugger and investigate where that mistake is. Debugging is very important!

Comment: You should also read about strings, especially the "terminating null" convention.

Comment: Please show plain text as text in your question. No screenshots needed.

Answer (score 5):

Your program has two issues:

#### 1.

```
char rev[strlen(s)];
```

You forgot to add an element for the string-terminating null character `'\0'`.

Use:

```
char rev[strlen(s) + 1];
```

---

Furthermore you also forgot to append this character at the end of the reversed string.

Use:

```
size_t len = strlen(s);
rev[len] = '\0';
```

Note, my `len` is the `k` in your provided code. I use the identifier `len` because it is more obvious what the intention of that object is. You can use `strlen(s)` because the string has the same length, doesn´t matter if it is in proper or reversed direction.

---

#### 2.

```
k=strlen(s);

for(i=0; i<strlen(s); i++)
{
    rev[k]=s[i];
    k--;
}
```

With `rev[k]` you accessing memory beyond the array `rev`, since index counting starts at `0`, not `1`. Thus, [the behavior is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

`k` needs to be `strlen(s) - 1`.

---

Three things to note:

1. The return value of `strlen()` is of type `size_t`, so an object of type `size_t` is appropriate to store the string length, not `int`.
2. It is more efficient to rather calculate the string length once, not at each condition test. Use a second object to store the string length and use this object in the condition of the `for` loop, like `i < len2`.
3. `char s[50]="Hi I Love Programming";` can be simplified to `char s[]="Hi I Love Programming";` - The compiler automatically detects the amount of elements needed to store the string + the terminating null character. This safes unnecessary memory space, but also ensures that the allocated space is sufficient to hold the string with the null character.

---

The code can also be simplified ([Online example](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qgA%2BhOSkAzpnbICeOpUy10AYVSsArgFtag1egAyeWpgByegEaZiXXgAdU0wktqad%2Bwc9eK6puZWurb2PDJymAruDATMxASeegacEfL%2BtLHxBIGWNnYOMnEJSd6p0sU5ZnkhBTwAlDKo2sTIHADkAKQATADMZsg6WJ296hX4qAB0CCPYnQAMAII9/bSD2sOjFcRmwNOzC8tLZgQA1LrMZhAAbqh46PWHnQDsAEKHp5%2BnyAjxp9KdACs70BABFTiNwT1ugAJPCnACSp2MqGumFOAAViKhgMRmLpdLtoSN3ksvv88AAvTBiM7sWgQ3rg7b0iDSR69UlHRbkn5/YiYa5A170iHdV6nThA0Ekj5fVzU2mnPD8WVLOWfGjECDwyGneakU58RngiCigC0ko5Et1o1O9JJyp673Fhr45vNjzJXxeXPJ5IFQuBfGlJv%2Bwrw0rVPJ9zxl6u9n0DwodYLDYC6gPU8wz0Y1p0cO3oVAg0IAKgh0YG7LJ/gQi8BldIQGLAQCs7RoYbA9annHDu1GqwQO1Ae1SAZ2vNx6gR%2Bp/s1WuiVpxxwQR9P6o0ANYgXq9Sb7o/Hk8ANiEI%2B448n09Is/a4%2BbBvXU8HpDgsBgiBQqF0jjw7BkBQEBoH%2BAEFMgwAAJzdKQVAAQQNaUNYG7jtYZjxAAniOq6kKBuiqAQADytCsNhr6kFgFyiOwqGUXgArRGizYUZgAAeUTaIhdEnHIdGsHg1h4sQmGaFgOFrjsugSY0ND0EwbAcOEAipMIoggBIYhSAJ1jNpAjSoI4GQseaADqbCsKcZnsfWzBWaZdjYsQ9mOJg6AiIoyCPpE0TKBARilCkpBGLkwShD4LhuHQgURX47ihfkYRpFEGRZCUWjJIIsjpDElQJbUSUVNkMXlHl1RhXUjTSIubRcEOI5jhOdH3mxAAcp7mqe3CnMAyDIKcUGTN0pwQLghAkGKvSpKcmhgYBk2cPUM1rqhW6kLugIGsO7RXqQ0mbU1FH3o%2BIDPqt75fhASDNAQjhceQlCgf%2BgGGPgRBJXJjAsLR4QAO54o4MkXqO17NSOK6nL9hAIKcbUdV1PV9QNQ0ra%2Ba2VswWD2BAO5cPMW2XuO%2B0GjeM4jidZ1o7j%2B6TNwUHzK1UGnr0gKtYC3C9NwsHbb0oNHeTpAvpuF3wB%2B35PeBQGPb%2Bz0QYMIjQfjcEIUhEAoRR6G0FhEl4b%2BBH0CRZF0VRCu0RR%2BCMYozF0exnHcRRvHbbeOnCaJGAdLh9Z4NJ7SrrJdBfYphQCNzCsaZIQiCXpON3kZ7gmQ5aIiQQCC7N5OV%2BQFGVlMFaj5eFqS%2BFFHjZ0FRcZPndTJb5mSVCV1epWVQSJVldel632SV2EVU1Up9Ug4dt4te1nXdfLojI/MkzzCNY3vQthqzbLzkrN0S3qKjm7UweJ670ewO7cTg9kw%2BMinYL51i1dIA3XdBAPSBMuSyAsFueNH0BwpP28P9zCA77b5tqNVJnecGfRhpQxTrDEeCNx6NkGlPW8QtByNAxljSg/dD4gAOiA46Z9KZb3WnuA8nBniAmeM8eYvQGacHAYCYGvNj6gNPsgta21uh8yHgLVhjQk6uGUNwIAA%3D%3D)):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char s[] = "Hi I Love Programming";
    size_t len = strlen(s);

    char rev[len + 1];
    size_t i,j;

    for(i = 0, j = (len - 1); i < len; i++, j--)
    {
        rev[j] = s[i];
    }

    rev[len] = '\0';

    printf("The reverse string is: %s\n", rev);
}
```

Output:

```
The reverse string is: pgnimmargorP evoL I iH
```

Comment: @ZahirulIslamNahid How did you changed the code of yours exactly? How did you edited it?

Comment: ```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char s[50]="Hi I Love Programming";
    char rev[strlen(s)+1];

    int i,k;
    int search[3];
    for(i=0; i<50; i++)
    {
        if(s[i]=='I')
            search[0]=1;
        if(s[i]=='p')
            search[1]=1;
        if(s[i]=='m')
            search[2]=1;
    }


    k=strlen(s);
    for(i=0; i<strlen(s); i++)
    {
        rev[k]=s[i];
        k--;
    }
    size_t len = strlen(rev);
    rev[len] = '\0';
    printf("The reverse string is: %s\n", rev);
}


```

Comment: @ZahirulIslamNahid Me fool. Change `size_t len = strlen(rev);` to `size_t len = strlen(s);` It is possible because string length keeps the same. The former won´t work as there isn´t a string in `rev`.

Comment: @ZahirulIslamNahid Also `k` shall be of type `size_t` too. Calculate `size_t len = strlen(rev);` once and then assign `len` to`len2` like: `size_t len2 = len;`. Use, `len2` instead of `k``.

Comment: @ZahirulIslamNahid I added how I rewrote your code in a simpler manner with the corrected parts mentioned above. It works at my machine. Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

your program is hard to understand. Here you have something much simpler (if you want to reverse the string of course)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *revstr(char *str)
{
    char *start = str;
    char *end;

    if(str && *str)
    {
        end = str + strlen(str) - 1;
        while(start < end)
        {
            char tmp = *end;
            *end-- = *start;
            *start++ = tmp;
        }
    }
    return str;
}


int main()
{
    char s[50]="Hi I Love Programming";

    printf("%s", revstr(s));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/5KX3kP